# Bokeh - display corresponding text on click

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to display simple text (on the *2nd plot*)  when ever user clicks on a circle on the *first plot*.
I stared with the working example on the **bokeh** website which displays first plot.

I made some changes below so that when user click a circle on the first plot the second plot should display the corresponding text.
So when user click circle on (x = 1, y =2)on the first plot then text displayed on 2nd Plot should be ('first')

With code below I don't see any plot at all and no errors ! I am sure how to debug this problem

I am open to different approach as well

[Plot of Circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGWYG.png)

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Plot, Range1d, Text
from bokeh.layouts import column

output_file("styling_selections.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x = [1,2,3],
                                    y = [2,5,3],
                                    name = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
                                    ))


plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="tap", title="Select a circle")
renderer = plot.circle(x= 'x', y= 'y', size=50,
                       # set visual properties for selected glyphs
                       selection_color="firebrick",    
                       # set visual properties for non-selected glyphs
                       nonselection_fill_alpha=0.2,
                       nonselection_fill_color="blue",
                       nonselection_line_color="firebrick",
                       nonselection_line_alpha=1.0,
                       source = source)

def construct_text_box(source): 
    # Plot and axes                                                             
    xdr = Range1d(0, 220)                                                       
    ydr = Range1d(0, 120)                                                       

    plot = Plot(                                                                
        x_range=xdr,                                                            
        y_range=ydr,                                                            
        #title="",                                                               
        plot_width=250,                                                         
        plot_height=120,                                                        
        min_border=0,                                                           
    )                                                                           
    # Add the writing                                                           
    country = Text(x=5, y=50, text='cpname', text_font_size='18pt', text_color="#FFFFF", text_font_style="bold")                    
    plot.add_glyph(source, Text(), selection_glyph=country)                     

    return plot

text_box = construct_text_box(source)
show(column(plot,text_box))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you be more specific what your question is? In which way does you code not work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code that prevent the plots from being displayed. Adjusting the following will at least display both plots. However, the second plot will just be your desired texts overlayed on top of each other. In order to get the functionality that you are looking for, I'd guess that you need to use callbacks:

```
  # changed text parameter from cpname to name, thats the column you use
  # FFFFF was white, you wouldn't see this, changed to black
    country = Text(x=5, y=50, text='name', text_color="#000000")
    plot.add_glyph(source, country)
```

If I find time, I'll look into the callback part later. But this should get you started in the right direcation at least.

/e: Here is a working example. As suspected before, adding a callback adds the functionality you wished for. The tricky part was the JavaScript code. I hope the commentary is enough to understand it:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, output_notebook, reset_output
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Plot, Range1d, Text, TapTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import column

reset_output()

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x = [1, 10, 16], y = [2, 20, 10],
                                    name_labels = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
                                    name_display = ['','','']
                                    ))

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="tap", title="Select a circle")
renderer = plot.circle(x= 'x', y= 'y', size=50,
                       # set visual properties for selected glyphs
                       selection_color="firebrick",    
                       # set visual properties for non-selected glyphs
                       nonselection_fill_alpha=0.2, nonselection_fill_color="blue",
                       nonselection_line_color="firebrick", nonselection_line_alpha=1.0,
                       source = source)

def construct_text_box(source): 
    # Plot and axes                                                             
    xdr = Range1d(0, 220)                                                       
    ydr = Range1d(0, 120)                                                       

    plot = Plot(                                                                
        x_range=xdr, y_range=ydr,                                                        
        plot_height=120, min_border=0,                                                           
    )                                                                           
    # Add the writing                                                           
    country = Text(x=5, y=50, text='name_display', text_color="#000000")
    plot.add_glyph(source, country)    
    return plot

output_notebook()

JS_CODE ="""
    // Get index of current selected datapoint
    sel_point_index = cb_data.source.attributes.selected["1d"]["indices"][0];     

    /* replace all name_display values with the name_label
       value of currently selected point */
    for (i=0; i < cb_data.source.data.name_labels.length; i++) {
        cb_data.source.data.name_display[i] = cb_data.source.data.name_labels[sel_point_index];
        }       
    cb_data.source.change.emit();
    """

newtaptool = plot.select(type=TapTool)
newtaptool.callback = CustomJS(code=JS_CODE)

text_box = construct_text_box(source)
show(column(plot, text_box))
```

Comment: Very good catch on **cpname** error.  This does display the two plots together...

Comment: did you adjust `add_glyph` as well?

Comment: Yes I had missed that step. Now it does display both... thanks for the follow up